# Is $\mathbb Z$ first-order definable in (the ring) $\mathbb{Z\times Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, model-theory

Is $\mathbb Z$ first-order definable in $\mathbb{Z\times Z}$ (using sum and product but obviously not the concept of "component")? I believe no but how may I prove it? Is this standard?

Comment: What are $Z$ and $X$? Abstract algebraic rings?

Comment: Sorry, X just stands here for "cartesian product", read "direct sum" 
Z are the integers. Sorry I am new here, I don't know how to use special math symbols

Comment: So, rephrasing: is the diagonal subring of the direct sum of the integers with itself first-order definable?

Comment: I proved, by a contradiction argument, that first-order-proving, for any finite set n, the inexistence of an injection from the set n+1(=n U {n}) to the set n is equivalent to first-order-proving induction, and so this should fail.
So I am trying to make an argument that first-order-defining the diagonal would prove the inexistence of such injections (n,phi(n)), which I may see as subsets of the (n+1 X n) rectangle that meet horizontal lines once.

Comment: I know that the first-order statement "$x$ has no multiplicative inverse" means it's either of the form (n,0) or (0,n) for an integer n. But because they're symmetric, I'm not sure you can differentiate between the two forms.

Comment: @Ohad: yes: the union of the coordinate axes is first-order definable (but as the set of zero divisors, not the non-invertible elements). The individual axes are not definable (the automorphism $(x, y) \mapsto (y, x)$ interchanges the two axes, while a definable set must be its own image under any automorpihsm).

Comment: Can't you define $P(x)$ as $\neg\exists y:x*y=e$, when $e$ is $(1,1)$, the multiplicative identity?

Comment: @Ohad: your $P(x)$ defines the set of non-units. I don't see the relevance to the question or the earlier comments.

Comment: Like Rob said, the union of axes but not the individual axes. We can define the property of being an idempotent but not identifying the idempotent (1,0) from (0,1). So we can define the projections of (m,n) as (m,0) and (0,n) but not as m, n, that is, we cannot compare them. That's because an element of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is defined intrinsically as a given being, say "a", but not as a pair of integers.

Comment: It seems very straightforward and intuitive that there is no first order finite formula to catch the diagonal this way but I don't know how to proceed formally for such a kind of proof. For second order, we can surely say "the elements that are left untouched by any ring automorphism"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking if the set $\Delta = \{(a, a) \mathrel{|} a \in \Bbb{Z}\}$
is definable using the first-order language of rings in the product ring $\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$.
I have not come across this before, but I believe the answer is no (as you suspected). To see this, choose variables $e$ and $f$ and
think of them as parameters such that $\{e, f\} = \{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$ (i.e., we know
that $e$ is one of $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ and $f$ is the other one, but we don't
know which is which). Consider the the annihilators of $f$ and $e$, i.e., the
sets defined by the formulas:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
E(x) & {:=} & xf = 0 \\
F(x) & {:=} &xe = 0
\end{array}
$$
I will refer to these sets as the $e$-axis and the $f$-axis. The multiplication and addition
of $\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$ make the $e$-axis into a ring with $e$ as the multiplicative identity
and likewise for the $f$-axis and $f$.
Now assume $\delta(x)$ is a formula defining $\Delta$ and consider the formula:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\rho(x, y) & {:=} & E(x) \land F(y) \land \exists z(\delta(z) \land z = x + y)
\end{array}
$$
Let $\phi$ be a formula parametrised by $e$ and $f$ and with no other free
variables that asserts that the $e$-axis and the $f$-axis are rings with
multiplicative identities $e$ and $f$ respectively  and that $\rho(x, y)$
defines a ring isomorphism between these rings. By easy algebra we can show
that  $\phi$ holds in $\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$ if $e$ and $f$ are interpreted so
that  $\{e, f\} = \{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$. Hence the following sentence holds in
$\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\Phi & {:=} & \exists e\exists f (ef = 0 \land e + f = 1 \land \phi)
\end{array}
$$
since in $\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$, $ef = 0$ and $e + f = 1$ iff
$\{e, f\} = \{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$.

Now take a non-standard model $A$ of the theory of $\Bbb{Z}$ and consider the
ring $\Bbb{Z}\times A$. By the Feferman-Vaught theorem, the first-order theory
of $\Bbb{Z}\times A$ is the same as the first-order theory of
$\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$. Hence, assuming there is a formula $\delta(x)$ defining
$\Delta$ in $\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$, the sentence $\Phi$ described above in terms of $\delta(x)$ holds
in $\Bbb{Z}\times A$.  But just as in $\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$, in $\Bbb{Z}\times
A$, $ef = 0$ and $e + f = 1$ imply that $\{e, f\} = \{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$ and
hence that $E(x)$ and $F(x)$ define the rings $\Bbb{Z}\times \{0\}$ and $\{0\}
\times A$ (or vice versa). But for such $e$ and $f$, $\phi$ asserts that these rings
are isomorphic, which is false. Hence $\Phi$ is false in $\Bbb{Z}\times A$ and
we have a contradiction. So $\Delta$
cannot be definable.

Comment: Thank you so much, Rob. This will help me a lot. So the formula $\rho$ would be an identification of $(m,0)$ with $(0,m)$ (which I also suspected being impossible to write down). The ϕ would assert that the two axes are rings but without being able to distinguish between the two, correct?  Then $\Phi$ would be the fact that there are two orthogonal (and we may possibly add "primitive") idempotents such that the ideals generated by them are rings with the same operations of ZXZ but with identities e and f and that are in isomorphic correspondence by $\rho$, correct?

Comment: Then I really have to study the Feferman-Vaught theorem...and what a "standard model" but I'll get there...

I was thinking, even in structures where you can tell the axes form one another (Z_2 X Z, or "saying <<n is even>> with a finite formula") this argument should work, as long as there is one copy with an infinite cardinality. Am I right?

Thank you again!

Comment: Your first comment is right. You will find information about Feferman-Vaught in Hodges' book on Model Theory or via google: all we need from it here is that the first-order theory of the product of two structures is a function of the first-order theories of the factor structures (but AFAIK, Feferman-Vaught is the only way to prove that). There is plenty of information online and in books about non-standard models. I don't see what you mean about  $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}$ or "$n$ is even": maybe you should make that the topic of another question.

Comment: I was wrong about $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}$: the diagonal is definable here by simply saying "any element of the form $a+a$ and any element of the form $a+a+1$". And so with a longer but finite formula is any direct sum of one copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ with several $\mathbb{Z}_{n_i}$'s. So if a ring is a direct sum of quotients of $\mathbb{Z}$ it seems that, in order for the diagonal $\mathbb{Z}$ not to be definable,one needs at least two copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ itself.

Comment: Yes, Rob, I am sorry, I will reformulate it in a new question. Just quickly pointing out that by $a$ I mean an element of the product ring and by $1$ I also mean the identity of the ring, $(\bar{1},1)$. And you definitely deserve more than an upvote. I just don't know how to do it, as I am new here. I am looking for it now! Thank you very much!

Comment: I did that...it keeps telling me "once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will publicly change the score" So unless you see another way (in which case tell me and I'll be more than glad to vote you up), I owe you one, Rob, I am not far from the 15 anyways. And it will probably automatically change as soon as I'm 15

Comment: it did indeed, I am 13 now. Don't worry, I won't forget.

Comment: There you go
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626990/definibility-of-mathbbz-in-product-rings