# Definibility of $\mathbb{Z}$ in product rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, model-theory

If $R$ is a product ring whose factors are in a finite number and are all quotients of $\mathbb{Z}$ (that is, either $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_n$'s ), is it a sufficient and necessary condition for the diagonal image of $\mathbb{Z}$ to be undefinable in it by a finite first-order formula, that there be at least two copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ among the factors?

Comment: How about if $R=\mathbb Z$ itself? Then your condition is not satisfied, but the formula $x=x$ defines the diagonal image.

Comment: @RobArthan: Correct. And when there's only one factor, then the diagonal image of $\mathbb Z$ _is_ the whole of $R$ ...

Comment: I think the OP probably meant to say "undefinable" rather than "definable" (based on the earlier question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1620658/is-mathbb-z-first-order-definable-in-the-ring-mathbbz-times-z).

Comment: Yes, I made many mistakes in the definition. First of all, I did not specified that I want a finite number of factors, otherwise I can't control the (infinite) $\mathbb{Z}_{n_i}$'s. Then the fact that the abelian group is $\mathbb{Z}$ may hide a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ structure behind an additive group $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ where (I did not think about it but) I believe we have many more tools to define $\mathbb{Z}$ which, by the way may not be called "diagonal"
And finally,as Rob Arthan says, I meant UNdefinable.

Comment: @Henning Makholm in $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ my "integers" are $(0,\bar{0}), (1,\bar{1}), (2,\bar{0}), (3,\bar{1}) \ldots $ so it is not everything

Comment: I believe if $R=\mathbb{Z}$ then an empty formula defines the integers but $x=x$ or any tautology is one that works.

Comment: @MarcusBarãoCamarão: There's no $\mathbb Z_2$ in my counterexample. It is just $R=\mathbb Z^1$ itself. It does not satisfy your proposed "necessary and sufficient" condition, but the diagonal is definable. Therefore your condition is at least not _necessary_.

Comment: @Henning Makholm
As I said, I mistook completely the word and what I wanted to say is "undefinable" instead of definable.

So the conjecture is that having at least 2 copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ is necessary and sufficient for the diagonal (integer multiples of the identity element $(1,1,\ldots ,1)$ ) to be UNDEFINABLE. I changed that already in the main question and I apologize for the misunderstanding.

And so $\mathbb{Z}$ is obviously definable in $\mathbb{Z}$ itself, as you pointed out.

Comment: @Marcus, Ah, okay.